# multiple resource column in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

How can I add multiple resource column in full calendar scheduler

```
resources: [
    { id: 'a', title: 'Room A' },
    { id: 'b', title: 'Room B' },
    { id: 'c', title: 'Room C' },
    { id: 'd', title: 'Room D' }
],
resources: [
    { id: 'a', title: 'Room A Info' },
    { id: 'b', title: 'Room B Info' },
    { id: 'c', title: 'Room C Info' },
    { id: 'd', title: 'Room D Info' }
]
```

Something like this with 2 or more resource column.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said exactly what you want the output to be , but to get the effect I think you want, you can use resource groups. Specify the following in your calendar options:

```
resourceGroupField: 'groupId',
resources: [
    {
        id: 1,
        groupId: 'a',
        title: 'Room A'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        groupId: 'b',
        title: 'Room B'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        groupId: 'c',
        title: 'Room C'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        groupId: 'd',
        title: 'Room D'
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        groupId: 'a',
        title: 'Room A Info'
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        groupId: 'b',
        title: 'Room B Info'
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        groupId: 'c',
        title: 'Room C Info'
    },
    {
        id: 8,
        groupId: 'd',
        title: 'Room D Info'
    }
]
```

See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resource_rendering/resourceGroupField/ for more info.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear on my question, what I need is 2 column of resource shown here https://fullcalendar.io/scheduler/ is one recourse column but I need 2 in a row(another resource just beside original resource)

Comment: Rooms 1 and Rooms 2 and 12am 1am and so on

Comment: Like this one? https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.7.0/demos/column-grouping.html

Comment: yeah I was going to say just do View Source on that page and you'll see exactly what to do :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
 resourceAreaColumns: [
  {
    field: 'field-one',
    headerContent: 'heading-one'
  },
  {
    field: 'field-two',
    headerContent: 'heading-two'
  }
],
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.